# Why don't we say Baruch Hu UVoruch Shmo more often?

Tags: halacha, blessing

I notice in Minyanim that I participate in that when the Chazan repeats the Shemonei Esrei and gets to "Baruch Ata Hashem", nearly everyone says "Baruch Hu UVoruch Shemo".

Yet, those same people skip other places where Hashem's name is said. Why, for example, doesn't "Refaeinu *Hashem*" get a "Baruch Hu..."?

Moreover, why don't people say it when hearing someone is saying Birkos Hanehenin/Tachanun/Shir Shel Yom (all places where one can interrupt)?

Comment: http://halachayomit.co.il/DisplayRead.asp?readID=1067

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10988

Comment: I know someone who says it for any birkas hanehenin he hears.

Comment: Tachanun and Shir Shel Yom are brachot?

Comment: Another instance where Ashkenazim (and some Sefaradim) refrain from saying it is when hearing Birkat HaKohanim. Yalqut Yosef states to refrain, or at least to answer inaudibly, so as not to confuse the Kohanim and the Sha"Tz.

Comment: @DanF I think the point of the question was to include _any_ time Hashem's name is said, even outside of _berachos_.

Comment: Can someone explain why it's opinion based?

Comment: @DoubleAA mostly _S'faradim_ IME.

Comment: @msh210 One Ashkenazi.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - you asked why some people don't do it. There can be all types of reasons, most notably because people are asleep, ignorant, etc. That's different from asking if there are minhagim stating not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igros Moshe ([OC 2:98](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=290)) explains that since there is no obligation to answer "*Baruch Hu U'varuch Shemo*", therefore people are accustomed to not answering it to individual *berachos*.