# Baruch Hu Uvaruch Shemo for Aneinu on a fast day

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, fast-days, hefsek-interruption, chazarat-hashatz

The shaliach tzibbur on a fast day adds a bracha in to his repetition of the amida, the Aneinu. Unlike other brachot, this is not a repetition because the individual davening has not said this. Therefore, is it proper for someone listening to the repetition NOT to say Baruch Hu Uvaruch Shemo to this bracha in order to be made Yotzei by its recitation, as per the rules enumerated in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11000/1362) answer? [this applies to someone who would otherwise say BHUVSh to the brachot in the repetition]

Comment: I figure if this were a _berakha_ for which you need to be _yotzei_, we would say it during the silent _shmoneh esrei_, no?

Comment: @Daniel in mincha, we do say it, but we fold it into another bracha. It is written in the plural so I assume it is said on behalf of people, not as a simple request of the shaliach tzibbur.

Comment: Danno, that is a _non sequitur_. If we had an obligation to say this _berakha_ that's the same as all the other _berakhot_ in _shmoneh esrei_, don't you think we would say it just like the other _berakhot_?

Comment: @Daniel so you are saying that the nature of this is as a personal request of the sha"tz which is irrelevant to the davening of the individual?

Comment: Perhaps. That's just my suggestion. I don't know that it's true.

Comment: Sounds like you guys should just ask why only the Shatz says it as it's own Berakha, before asking questions based on answers to that... (@Daniel Danno)