# Being Yotzei through someone else's Bracha (and physical movement)

Tags: tefilla

When the chazzan says the birchot hashachar, there seems to be a practice of NOT saying baruch hu vvaruch sh'mo so that the [individual](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=2326) listening and saying amein can be made [yotzei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11000/1362) through the chazzan's words.

There is also a practice of touching the tefillin during certain of the [brachot](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Putting_On_and_Removing_Tefillin). Combining these two practices, would one becoming exempt through the chazzan's reading make the motions of touching the tefillin (is it as if he is saying the blessings) or not because the touching is only part of a personal "saying"?

[I can't think right now of many other situations where saying is coupled with movement, and yet the individual can be exempted through someone else's saying -- but if other cases exist, then I presume that this question would apply there as well. One possibility is one who does not know to daven being exempted for shmoneh esrei by listening to the Shatz -- should the individual bow (and/or strike his chest) at the appropriate moments?]

Comment: While I'm not sure I agree with the premise of your question, an example of this phenomenon would be birkhat kohanim and the kohen's hand position. Beit Haleivi discusses shome'a k'oneh for birkhat kohanim (need to dig up the reference) but from what I remember his focus is on the requirement for reciting birkhat kohanim out loud, and whether that is fulfilled by shome'a k'oneh.

Comment: There's also the chiddush about everyone saying the 10 sons of Haman because you can't fulfill saying them in one breath using shomeia keoneh.  (I think this is mostly rejected as the reason for the minhag.)

Comment: @Heshy Yes. That's from the Rogatchover.

Comment: "One possibility is one who does not know to daven being exempted for shmoneh esrei by listening to the Shatz -- should the individual bow (and/or strike his chest) at the appropriate moments?" That seems like a way better example!!

Comment: IME it is generally assumed no one is yotzei through the leaders recitation of morning blessings. As your link says "That is why most people say [Barukh Hu uVarukh Shemo] by the morning brachos... either because they've already said it, or because they want to make their own."

Comment: Or also shaking the lulav if you're yotzei hallel with the chazzan.

Comment: Re the reasoning behind what happens in *Birkot Hashachar*, in most shuls I've attended, people **do** say *baruch hu...*. Then, they repeat the brachot silently after the Shat"z is done. It seems that there are various *minhagim*. I think there's a beureihatefilah article that discusses this. If I find it, I'll contact you with the link.