# Why is Baruch-Hu-Uvaruch-Shmo answered only in the brachos after the Haftorah, but not in the bracha before?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, blessing, haftarah

As far as I recall, the minhag in all Ashkenaz shuls which I have ever attended, was not to answer *Baruch-Hu-Uvaruch-Shmo* to the name of Hashem in the Bracha which is said before the *Haftorah*, but in the brachos which are said after the *Haftorah*, the congregation does answer *Baruch-Hu-Uvaruch-Shmo*.

Does anyone know of a source/reason for this?

Comment: It fits into the tune for the after-berachos but does not fit into the tune for the before-berachos.

Comment: @Alex BHUS should ALWAYS be said unless there is reason not to. Are you insinuating that really it should not have been said in EITHER of the brachos, but is said only because of the tune??? Besides, I just sang both of the brachos and was easily able to fit the BHUS into the tune of the first bracha too.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10988/15256

Comment: @Kazibácsi As others have already pointed out, the concensus seems to be that when one is yotzei with the brachos one should not say BHUS. But my question still stands, Why the difference between the before bracha and the after brachos. Are we yotzei with only the first and not  the rest of the brachos?

Comment: Once the haftarah has been completed, the *mitzvah* has been completed. There may be a completely different reason as to why there are brachot said after the mitzvah has been performed. But, as it has been already done, what would be the problem of responding to the brachot after haftarah?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=290